# ExtJS defined combobox change event not firing

Tags: extjs

I have a grid and rowEditing plugin in ExtJS 6.0.1
One column in the grid is a custom combobox component that I've defined.
Custom comboBox component has a change event. But it is not firing.

Here is the codes;

```
**//RowEditing Plugin**
var rowEditing = Ext.create('Ext.grid.plugin.RowEditing', {
    clicksToMoveEditor: 1,
    autoCancel: false,
    clicksToEdit: 1,
    saveBtnText: 'Kaydet',
    cancelBtnText: 'Vazgeç',
    editing: true,
    listeners: {
        edit: function (editor, context, eOpts) {

        }
    }
});

**//GridPanel**
Ext.define('MailToTicketPersonsGrid', {
    extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',
    xtype: 'MailToTicketPersonsGrid',
    id: 'mailToTicketPersonsGrid',
    store: mailToTicketPersonsStore,
    plugins: [rowEditing],
    columns: {
        items: [
            {
                text: 'Mail',
                flex: 1,
                dataIndex: 'mail'
            },
            {
                text: 'Ad',
                flex: 1,
                dataIndex: 'name',
                editor: {
                    xtype: 'textfield',
                }
            },
            {
                text: 'Soyad',
                flex: 1,
                dataIndex: 'lastName',
                editor: {
                    xtype: 'textfield',
                }
            },
            {
                text: 'Telefon',
                flex: 1,
                dataIndex: 'phone',
                editor: {
                    xtype: 'textfield',
                }
            },
            {
                text: 'Şirket',
                flex: 1,
                editor: {
                    xtype: 'CompanySearch',                        
                }
            }
        ]
    }
});


**//Window**
Ext.create('Ext.window.Window', {
    id: 'createUserWindow',
    layout: 'fit',
    border: 0,
    resizable: false,
    modal: true,
    bodyPadding: 10,
    width: 600,
    height: 300,
    listeners: {
        show: function () {

        },
        close: function () {
            Ext.getBody().unmask();
        }
    },
    items: [
        {
            xtype: 'panel',
            border: 0,
            layout: {
                type: 'vbox',
                align: 'stretch',
                pack: 'start'
            },
            items: [
                {
                    xtype: 'MailToTicketPersonsGrid',//grid
                    flex: 1
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}).show();


**//Custom ComboBox**
    Ext.define('companySearch', {
    extend: 'Ext.form.field.ComboBox',
    xtype: 'CompanySearch',
    emptyText: 'Şirket ara...',
    editable: true,
    listeners: {
        change: function (field, newValue, oldValue, eOpts) {
            alert(newValue);
        }
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont know whats wrong with your code but here is a working [Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/1tib)
maybe you passing parameters in function or something else i dont know but you can compare this fiddle to your code
hope it will work :)

```
editable: true,
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but my comboBox is an editable comboBox like a textBox. change event not firing while i'm writing any text in comboBox

Comment: I set it true now Happy :)

Comment: if you have got your answer please accept it to close the question

Comment: I copied - pasted your codes and it works fine :D :D. 
Thanks for the reply @Salman hassan OkZ